# Display username on frontpage after login javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a problem displaying the username after a succesful login. Would appreciate some guidance. I've just created a small 'UserDB' in javascript from where the name displayed should be collected. I can link my login page too if needed. Thanks guys - appreciate your help.
Mathias.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <title>Registrer Pant</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="forside.css">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <script src="LogUd.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="header">
    <!-- Log ud knap  -->
    <button id="logUd" onclick="logOut()">Log ud</button>

    <script>
        function logOut() {
            document.location.href = "1logInd.html";
        }
    </script>
    <h1>Velkommen, username</h1>

</div>


<div class ="container">
    <div class ="box"><a href="Velgørenhed.html">
        <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h3>Nexus fordele</h3>
            <p>Her kan du se dine optjente fordele i Cafe Nexus</p>
        </div> </a>
    </div>
    <div class ="box"><a href="RegistreringAfPant.html">
        <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-recycle" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        <div class="content">
            <h3> Registrer pant </h3>
            <p>Her kan du registere dine pant A, B eller C flasker</p>
        </div> </a>
    </div>
    <div class ="box"><a href="Panthistorik.html">
    <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    <div class="content">
        <h3>Samlet donation</h3>
        <p>Her kan du se hvor meget, du har doneret i alt</p>
    </div> </a>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.container
{
    position: relative;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 50px auto;

}
/* Definerer formen for alle bokse */
.container .box
{
    position: relative;
    width: calc(400px - 30px);
    height: calc(300px - 30px);
    background: #000;
    float: left;
    margin: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
/* Definerer den enkelte boks */
.container .box .icon
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #f00;
    transition: 0,5s;
    z-index: 1;
}
/* hover settings - Mouseover funktion */
.container .box:hover .icon
{
    top: 20px;
    left: calc(50% - 40px);
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.container .box .icon .fa
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    font-size: 80px;
    transition: 0,5s;
    color: #fff;
}
.container .box:hover .icon .fa
{
    font-size: 40px;
}
.container .box .content
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    height: calc(100%-100px);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 25px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: 0,5s;
    opacity: 0;
}
.container .box:hover .content
{
    top: 100px;
    opacity: 1;

}
.container .box .content h3
{
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
}
.container .box .content p
{
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
}
.container .box:nth-child(1) .icon
{
    background: #B18904;
}
.container .box:nth-child(1)
{
    background: #B18904;
}
.container .box:nth-child(2) .icon
{
    background: #4967AA;
}
.container .box:nth-child(2)
{
    background: #4967AA;
}
.container .box:nth-child(3) .icon
{
    background: #BCBCBA;
}
.container .box:nth-child(3)
{
    background: #BCBCBA;
}

.header {
    padding: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #4967AA;
    color: white;
}

.header h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
}

#logUd{

    position:fixed;
    right:1%;
    top:1%;
    float: right;
}
```

My userDB:

```
class User {
    constructor(brugernavn, kodeord){
        this.brugernavn = brugernavn;
        this.kodeord = kodeord;
    }
}
if(localStorage.getItem('User') == null) {
    var userList = [];
    userList.push(new User('Alexandra', 'alexandra123'));
    userList.push(new User('Magnus', 'magnus123'));
    userList.push(new User('Mathias','mathias123'));
    userList.push(new User('Kasper','kasper123'));
    userList.push(new User('123','123'));


    var userListString = JSON.stringify(userList)
    localStorage.setItem('User', userListString)
}
```

Comment: I can not see where you are trying to call this ```LogIn``` method in your code. There is only  ```LogOut```. If you can please show code which contains this function. Or maybe you want to display **username** after user ```LogOut```?

Comment: If u want in next page than get and set the username in cookies and get the value in next page

Comment: My login page looks like this:

HTML: https://www.codepile.net/pile/XZY1B5Z8
CSS: https://www.codepile.net/pile/LQJgzAl6
JS: https://www.codepile.net/pile/OLlp24LA

Afer a succesful login from 1 of the 5 users in 'userDB' you'll get forwarded to the frontpage i linked to in my first post. I'm not quite sure how to call the LogIn method.